# require is not defined in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am trying to run a html file in Firebase staging environment. I have used **Firebase** npm package in the js code. But while running in the browser it throws error "require is not defined".

**HTML Code:**

```
<html>   
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/test.js"></script>
</html>
```

**JS Code:**

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var dataRef = new Firebase('firebase url');
console.log("Firebase : "+Firebase+" -- dataRef :: "+dataRef)
dataRef.set("Firebase Require");
```

Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: is the `JS code` your `test.js` file?

Comment: yes , it's the test.js file

Comment: require doesn't exist in the web API and it is not implemented by any browser. You can think about using a tool such as https://webpack.js.org/get-started/install-webpack/ if you want to import npm frontend packages directly

Comment: will the webpack modules will work in Firebase hosting

Comment: of course, I am using it in this project https://github.com/francescoes/scrabble, have a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup a tool (such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)) to manage your dependencies. In this way you will be able to `require` (or `import` es6 sintax) libraries directly in your `.js` files.

A possible setup could be the following:

in `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
}
```

To tell webpack which is the `entry` file of your app and let it build the `bundle` for you.

Then in `index.js` you can use:

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';
var dataRef = new Firebase('firebase url');
console.log("Firebase : "+Firebase+" -- dataRef :: "+dataRef)
dataRef.set("Firebase Require");
```

Refer to https://webpack.js.org/configuration/ for a more complete guide.

p.s. that will be valid for every node dependecies with frontend support

Comment: You realise this is just making his coding experience worse as he does not understand the difference between server-side modules and how exactly they should be used. But whatever, seems like trying to help people on SO and give them the correct info on what they should do is pointless. The answers which are mot-a-mot, copy paste solutions are accepted rather than hinting users what they have to do so they can learn it themselves. Cheers

Comment: Hi @Eduard, take it easy. Surely I cannot start from paleolitic to give an answer on stackoverflow. The guy downloaded a npm package that is for frontend usage, then he didn't know that `require` is not allowed outside the `node` world. When you are new to javascript, it can happen, He will learn, but one also need to get things done.

Answer (score 2):

This happens becaure `require` does not exist on the `client-side`. Note that `npm` packages, just as `nodeJS` as a service, are `backend` services.

Therefore you need to include Firebase's SDK via the following:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js"></script>
```

Then initialise the SDK using the config you need. The setup is explaing here in more detail: https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.1/firebase.js

Cheers!

Comment: yes this solution i know , but it will solve only for firebase.js  , what if i will add more other node modules in my application , then still i will get require is not defined error in Firebase hosting

Comment: @DeeptimanPattnaik You need to understand there is a difference between server-side and client-side. Afterall, why do you need to use nodeJS ? You can simply add Firebase's SDK just as that link shows you in an `index.html` file on your desktop, and there you have it.

Npm packages, and everything regarding NodeJS is related to backend processing, just like you do in PHP if you have any experience. You process data in your app.js / test.js or w/e file, then you output an answer for that route, or save some data in some DB. You can't use require on client side unless you run webpack or others

Comment: My concerned not only Firebase , in my web application Firebase as well as other node modules are included , and i am trying to host in Firebase , so this creates problem for me

Comment: Question.. are you aware of the difference between client and server side ? I can do whatever type of Firebase app you want, without having to use NodeJS whatsoever.

Comment: yes brother , nowadays a kid also knows about client and server side , ok can you please let me know , how to integrate sendgrid in a Firebase app

Comment: I said `Firebase app` not Sendgrid apps. 

Inside your `app.js` ( main file ) you can require all the modules you need, preferrably use ExpressJS to make a distinction between requests. So, require a sendgrid module inside `app.js`, configure and initialise it, then, route a request `app.post('/send', ( req, res ) => { sendgrid send email code })`. Now you have the send email part using Sendgrid in nodejs, though you can do it with any other language as well. Then, in your /public folder, init index.html with the link I gave you above with Firebase, then..

Comment: When the action is detected in your Firebase client code, make a post request towards your nodeJS app "/send" with the email data you need to send. And that's it.