# Javascript error - Require is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, node-modules

I am trying to connect my web app to firebase database. When using a local server to host the website, i get error `index.js:11 Uncaught ReferenceError: Require is not defined`

I installed npm firebase-tools and I believe that my html and js setup is correct.

I don't really know how to move forward from here. All help is welcome.

Code Snippets

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    
        <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
    
        <script src="index.js"></script>



// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAOjGyQG0eHQLqXomKYKTpdg0tmwaZvaiU",
    authDomain: "library-app-d49fe.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://library-app-d49fe.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "library-app-d49fe",
    storageBucket: "library-app-d49fe.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "168203985001",
    appId: "1:168203985001:web:d79809c549371b5df642f8"
};

const firebase = require("firebase");

// Required for side-effects
require("firebase/firestore");
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884416/require-is-not-defined-in-firebase) answer could help you. Or you already seen it?

Comment: check out  this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#additional_setup_options) maybe you need to add defer to script tag

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito yes, I saw it,  but I don't really understand it.

Comment: **Update:** I removed those 2 lines that contain required in my JS file and everything is working well now - i got my entries in the database. Anyone able to explain me why that is the case?

Comment: require doesnt work on web browser, it's for nodejs from server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your project is standard web project (no module bundler present). That is why you can't use [`require()`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require), which is a Node.js API.

If this is indeed the case, then you can [setup firebase using their CDN's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#from-the-cdn):

**`index.html`**

```
<body>
  <!-- Firebase App -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <!-- Firestore -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <!-- Your custom JS file -->
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**`index.js`**

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDOCAbC123dEf456GhI789jKl01-MnO",
  authDomain: "myapp-project-123.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://myapp-project-123.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "myapp-project-123",
  storageBucket: "myapp-project-123.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "65211879809",
  appId: "1:65211879909:web:3ae38ef1cdcb2e01fe5f0c",
  measurementId: "G-8GSGZQ44ST"
};


firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

If you're using firestore, you can create an instance of it, and assign it to a constant for later use:

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

That should do it.

To learn more about `require()`, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901082/what-is-this-javascript-require).